# Access Microsoft Band 2 sensors through computer

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm trying to write a program that collects the pedometer and 
heart rate data stream from the Microsoft Band 2. I've written an
android app that does this but is it possible to do this without a
smartphone and directly stream the data to a computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Band SDK can be used with Windows Store 8.1 and Windows 10 Universal applications; you just Bluetooth-pair the Band to the PC and applications can stream sensor data from the Band just like their phone equivalents.

The Band SDK does not support OS X and I don't know whether it can be used in any arbitrary device running an Android-derived OS.

Comment: How much work would it require to support OS X.... I'd like to start producing some apps and wondering if i can patch the SDK. (that would be... awesome)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know--I'm least familiar with the iOS SDK and don't know how similar its Bluetooth stack is to the OS X Bluetooth stack.  You can create/vote for the idea on Uservoice: https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band

Comment: This is not currently supported. But you can make a feature request on http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band